# Append text to currently selected div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm working on this website www.betamaths.eu

When a user had clicked inside one of the divs that have placeholder text and then click a button on the left, I would like the text from that button to append inside the div.

I have this code from another user which appends or prepends text ouside the div (not what I am looking for. You can test it with the lowercase alpha button in the menu on the left of the webpage listed above if you wish to get a better understanding.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var No = 0;
var focusedElement;
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#answer_step1').on('click','div',function() {
        focusedElement = this;
    });

    $('#alpha').on('click',function() {
        $('#answer_step1').prepend('<div>Test'+No+'</div>');
        No++
    });
});
```

If I change the line

```
$('#answer_step1').append('<div>Test'+No+'</div>');
```

to

```
$('#answer_step1').append('Test'+No);
```

nothing happens. Any help is appreciated. If I can get one of these working, the rest will be easy.

Comment: I guess the answer you are looking for, is not in the JS code. It should be in CSS. I assume you have some CSS codes which needs the text be wrapped in div

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must have a syntatically error in your code, because I used your same code and was able to accomplish the `append();`

**HTML:**

```
<button id="alpha">
Click
</button>

<div id="answer_step1">
hi
</div>
```

**Javascript:**

```
var No = 0;
var focusedElement;

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#answer_step1').on('click','div',function() {
        focusedElement = this;
    });

    $('#alpha').on('click',function() {
        $('#answer_step1').prepend('Test' + No);
        No++
    });
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/typtzr7z/

Comment: I tried copy/paste your work above and it works. Thanks for looking into this